# What is the format of user pool id for AWS CognitoIdentity?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I need to get a list of users in my Cognito pool using AWS javascript SDK. I was going to use CognitoIdentity class and the following method to get user list:

```
var params = {
  IdentityPoolId: 'STRING_VALUE', /* required */
  ...
};
cognitoidentity.listIdentities(params, function(err, data) {
  ...
});
```

However, it requires IdentityPoolId in a very strange format:

```
An identity pool ID in the format REGION:GUID.
```

The check for which looks like:

```
[\w-]+:[0-9a-f-]+
```

That is, region name should be without numbers. However, most of the regions have numbers, for example, my region is "ap-northeast-1".
Both Pool Id and Pool ARN values don't match.
What is the real format of this id and where to get the value for my user pool?

Answer (score 2):

The example of the `IdentityPoolId` is provided in the API documentation for [ListIdentities](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognitoidentity/latest/APIReference/API_ListIdentities.html#API_ListIdentities_RequestSyntax):

> An identity pool ID in the format REGION:GUID.
>
> Pattern: [\w-]+:[0-9a-f-]+

[Example given](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognitoidentity/latest/APIReference/API_ListIdentities.html#API_ListIdentities_Examples):

```
"IdentityPoolId": "us-east-1:509f9747-5b5d-484e-a2d7-74fcba108147"
```

Comment: I haven't seen that, thank you! However, I still don't understand the format. What is "GUID" then and where to get it in Cognito web interface? Looks like I don't understand what is Cognito identity, I thought it is user account and I don't see any another method to get the list of users (there is CognitoIdentityServiceProvider, but it allows to get users only one by one).

Comment: @ArseniiFomin Not sure about console. Dont have any pool at present to check. Sorry.